# Time in Stack Overflow bug

Tags: support

[image: Time]

I am seeing the same date and time for a long time, and it is not changing. Why so?

Comment: You mean why the SO developer team doesn't deploy a new version of this site every second to get an accurate clock?

Answer (score 18):

It isn't changing because we didn't deploy there since.

Those are build numbers/versions, not the current date.

Also - that's not Stack Overflow. It is stackexchange.com.

Comment: ya correct. I took the screenshot from SE leagues. There is an update yesterday am I correct?

Comment: A software deploy? No. We don't deploy the site every day. The database gets updated daily. That's a different thing.

Comment: To be clear @Sagar - that isn't a date and time; it is the ID of the current version of the site's *code* that *happens* to be structured a bit like a date and time. People work on the site all the time, and every time a change is published the version number changes.

Comment: As this is on hold as off topic, I am not able to remove it. @Oded will you delete this question please

Comment: @SagarV - you can't remove it because it has an upvoted answer. I will not remove it as the question (and answer) contain information that is useful for future visitors who may have the same question. If the community decides to remove it, so be it.